# Optimum number of iterations when visualizing deep network

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I'm reading through [keras-visualization](https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html) document and the number of iterations when computing the gradient with respect to the filter activation loss was set to 20:

```
for i in range(20):
    loss_value, grads_value = iterate([input_img_data])
    input_img_data += grads_value * step
```

Now, if I want to find the optimum number of iterations, how to find it? Should I wait until the gradient becomes zero and use the second derivative test whether it's a max or min value? If yes, are there already built-in functions in keras that support this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean epochs when you say the best number of iterations? If so, I recommend that you set an early stopping, where the loss function value does not change for a while means that it converges and finds the best epochs.

Comment: I don't think this is related to epochs. No data passing here.